# Geometries for census tracts in 2012 and 2013 ACS 5 Releases

Tags: api, us-census

The Census API provides ACS 5 data for [2011](http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/acs-5year.2011.html) and [2012](http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/acs-5year.2012.html) (along with more recent years).

The Census's TIGERweb services provides census tract geometries for the [2013 ACS release](https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_ACS2013/MapServer/8) and the [2010 Decennial Census](https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_Census2010/MapServer/14).

Are the census tracts used in the 2011 ACS and 2012 ACS the same as either the 2010 or 2013 geometries? If not, is there a web service that provides the 2011 and 2012 geometries?

Comment: Are you in need of the formats provided by the API system or are you willing to go into GIS shaepfile / GDB territory?

Comment: Hi @Kotebiya, I am looking for a web service that provides appropriate geometries for the 2011 and 2012 ACS.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that it is recommended to use 2013 Census Tracts for 2013 ACS data and 2010 Census Tracts for 2010 Census Data. You could try using shapefile data for [2011](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2011/BG/) and [2012](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/BG/) data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Census website, for both the 2012 and 2011 Estimate Year, Census Tract uses the 2010 Census (https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/geography-acs/geography-boundaries-by-year.2012.html and https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/geography-acs/geography-boundaries-by-year.2011.html)